# Understanding fork() in linux

Tags: c, linux, fork

i have following code

```
void main()
{

pid_t pid,pid1;

pid = fork();

if(pid==0)
{
  pid1= getpid();

  printf("\n Child A %d" ,pid);
  printf("\n Child B %d",pid1);
}
else
{

  pid1 = getpid();
  printf("\n Parent C %d:",pid); 
  printf("\nParent d %d:",pid1);

 }
}
```

i am not understanding why i am getting same Process id for B and C. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Aren't your print statements a little mixed up? If `fork` returns `0`, then you are in the child process, so printing `pid` will yield `0`, and printing `pid1` (resulting from a `getpid` call within the child) will be the pid of the child. If you are in the parent, then `pid` is the pid of the *child* process, and `pid1` (resulting from a `getpid` call within the parent) is the pid of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
pid1 = getpid();
```

That is run in the child process and hence gives the child process id.

```
pid = fork();
```

That is initiated from the parent process but the return value is available to both parent and child. However, it returns a different value to the parent and child processes. Straight from the [fork man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork):

> the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is
>   returned in the child

So in both cases (B and C), it is the pid of the child process.

Answer (score 0):

This code is ran by two processes, one is the parent and the other is children. p process - return id of c process and c process return 0. i think your program maybe a demo of fork(), so it might be like this:

```
void main()
{

pid_t pid,pid1;

pid = fork();

if(pid==0)
{
pid1= getpid();

printf("\n i am Child A %d" ,pid1);
printf("\n Parent A %d",getppid());
}
else
{

pid1 = getpid();
printf("\n i am Parent B %d:",pid1);
printf("\n Children B %d:",pid); 


 }
}
```